# Installing 51Degrees onto all installed versions of Visual Studio

Tags: 51degrees

I've just installed 51Degrees for a VS2010 project I'm working on, but the retarded thing just doesn't want to work on VS2010, it's installing onto VS2012.

I need this to be working on VS2010 because I can't upgrade this project to VS2012 because I don't have it installed at the office and my laptop there won't run VS2012 anyway.

So how can I get this stupid thing to work on all versions of Visual Studio that I'm running?

Answer (score 0):

Install 51Degrees from NuGet.

Search 51Degrees.mobi in the Online packages.